# Android EditText search while typing in ListView fast delete issue

Tags: android, filter, android-edittext, listactivity, textwatcher

I have a problem with my code, I perform a search into a HashMap inside an Adapter. It works fine but when I delete quickly all letters in EditText so the Adapter show the list of the first entire string typed and not the list of all elements.

Example: 
I type James, the view get all the James in the Map, but if I delete quickly the EditText (pressing back) so the method perform the search right back and show the correct list for any substring (jame, jam, ja, j) but at the end he shows again the list inherited "James" and not the full contact list

Thank you for any answers!

```
public class ContactsActivity extends ListActivity {

private HashMap<String, UserEntry> all_map_jid=new HashMap<String, UserEntry>();
private ArrayList<String> all_mkey=new ArrayList<String>();



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
    getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);


    final EditText searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbox);


    TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            //... your logic
             adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // ... your logic

        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // ... your logic
        }
    };

    searchText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);}


public class RosterAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    //private ViewHolder holder;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    private HashMap<String, UserEntry> mappa_users=null;
    private ArrayList<String> mKeys;

    public RosterAdapter(){
        this.mappa_users =new HashMap<String, UserEntry>();
        this.inflater=          (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.mKeys=new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mappa_users.size();
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntry getItem(int position) {
        return mappa_users.get(mKeys.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }


     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



        ViewHolder holder;


        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row, null);

            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children
            // views we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_info);
            holder.availability = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_availability);
            holder.user_ic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);


            // Keep track of the view holder as a tag of the view
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
        }



        String user = getItem(position).getUserName();
        //Log.e("Nome","username "+user);
        holder.username.setText(user);



        if(!(getItem(position).getUserStatus())){

            System.out.println("unavailable");
            holder.availability.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_not_available);  

        }else{

            holder.availability.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_available);
        }

        //do your view stuff here

        return convertView;
    }





    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {                 
                mappa_users = (HashMap<String,UserEntry>) results.values;
                mKeys= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(mappa_users.keySet().toArray(new String[mappa_users.size()])));
                Collections.sort(mKeys, new RosterEntryComparator(mappa_users));

                notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                HashMap<String,UserEntry> searched_user=new HashMap<String,UserEntry>();
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();


                if (constraint!= null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {

                SmithWaterman metric = new SmithWaterman();

               for(String element : all_mkey){
                   //La mappa dell'adapter è riempito con le sole entry simily all'occorrenza ricercata
                   if (metric.getSimilarity(constraint.toString().toLowerCase(), all_map_jid.get(element).getUserName().toLowerCase()) >= 0.8 ){

                       UserEntry rEntry=all_map_jid.get(element);

                       searched_user.put(element, rEntry );

                   }

               }

              results.values = searched_user;
              results.count = searched_user.size();

                }
                else{


                        results.values = all_map_jid;
                        results.count = all_map_jid.size();

                }

                return results;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: I didn't quite fully understand the problem but you should have a copy of the original values in the adapter, which you would use for filtering(to always do the filtering on the full set of values) and which you don't modify.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried to put inside the adapter all_map_jid, that is the copy of the original values, but the problem is still here.
After typed if I delete quickly all the letters at the end the adapter don't show the full list (all_map_jid) but an itermediate version of mappa_users

Comment: If you solved the problem post an answer and mark it as correct instead of editing the question to add the solution.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm a new user and I can post an answer only in another four hours. I will. Thank you again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved**

I solved the issue, the problem was that I created a new Filter object on any new typing, using the same Filter all works well, because as is written in the android documentation:

> public final void filter (CharSequence constraint,
>   Filter.FilterListener listener)
>
> Added in API level 1 Starts an asynchronous filtering operation.
>   Calling this method cancels all previous non-executed filtering
>   requests and posts a new filtering request that will be executed
>   later.

This is the correct code:

```
//My Adapter 
public class RosterAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{

    //private ViewHolder holder;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private ItemsFilter mFilter;

    private HashMap<String, UserEntry> mappa_users=null;
    private HashMap<String, UserEntry> all_map_jid=null;
    private ArrayList<String> all_mkey=null;;
    private ArrayList<String> mKeys;


    public RosterAdapter(){
        this.mappa_users =new HashMap<String, UserEntry>();
        this.inflater= (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.all_map_jid=new HashMap<String, UserEntry>();
        this.all_mkey=new ArrayList<String>();
        this.mKeys=new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mappa_users.size();
    }

    @Override
    public UserEntry getItem(int position) {
        return mappa_users.get(mKeys.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return arg0;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



        ViewHolder holder;


        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row, null);

            // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children
            // views we want to bind data to.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_info);
            holder.availability = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_availability);
            holder.user_ic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);


            // Keep track of the view holder as a tag of the view
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
            // and the ImageView.
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); 
        }



        String user = getItem(position).getUserName();
        //Log.e("Nome","username "+user);
        holder.username.setText(user);



        if(!(getItem(position).getUserStatus())){


            holder.availability.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_not_available);  

        }else{

            holder.availability.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_available);
        }

        //do your view stuff here

        return convertView;
    }





    /**
     * Implementing the Filterable interface.
     */
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ItemsFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;}


        /**
         * Custom Filter implementation for the items adapter.
         *
         */
        private class ItemsFilter extends Filter {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                adapter.mappa_users = (HashMap<String,UserEntry>) results.values;
                adapter.mKeys= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(adapter.mappa_users.keySet().toArray(new String[adapter.mappa_users.size()])));
                Collections.sort(mKeys, new RosterEntryComparator(adapter.mappa_users));

                notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.e("fine", "Terminato filtraggio "+constraint);

                }


            @Override
            protected  FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                HashMap<String,UserEntry> searched_user=new HashMap<String,UserEntry>();
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();


                if (constraint!= null && constraint.toString().length() > 0) {

                SmithWaterman metric = new SmithWaterman();

               for(String element : all_mkey){
                   //La mappa dell'adapter è riempito con le sole entry simily all'occorrenza ricercata
                   if (metric.getSimilarity(constraint.toString().toLowerCase(), all_map_jid.get(element).getUserName().toLowerCase()) >= 0.8 ){

                       UserEntry rEntry=all_map_jid.get(element);

                       searched_user.put(element, rEntry );

                   }

               }

              results.values = searched_user;
              results.count = searched_user.size();

                }
                else{


                        results.values = all_map_jid;
                        results.count = all_map_jid.size();

                }

                return results;
            }
        };
```